# how to send and receive sms through java using twilio

Tags: java, generics, twilio

so here's the program I want to write the same program without using `generics` and `Twilio`. I don't have knowledge of `Java generics` and I want to do this program simply user interface.

provide me simple java program to do so.

```
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

//Pre-requisite apache http and twilio java libraries
public class Sms {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = 
        System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = 
        System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

    public static final String YOUR_NUMBER = "1231231231";
    public static final String HER_NUMBER = "3213213213";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException { 

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, 
  AUTH_TOKEN);

        String[] randomMessages = {
            "i got to work",
            "i got to exercise",
            "i got to study",
        }; 

        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(randomMessages.length);
        String finalMessage = (randomMessages[randomIndex]);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Late at work. " + 
           finalMessage));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", YOUR_NUMBER));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", HER_NUMBER));

        MessageFactory messageFactory = 
            client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
        Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
        System.out.println(mess`enter code here`age.getSid());
    }
}
```

so here's the program I want to write the same program without using `generics` and `Twilio`. I don't have knowledge of `Java generics` and I want to do this program simply user interface.

provide me simple java program to do so.

Comment: First off hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Secondly, I'm pretty sure that code won't compile. If you want any help removing generics, you need to provide working code in the first place. Thirdly, its really unclear exactly what your looking for, you say "without using generics and twilio" but you can't not use Twilio when your using the Twilio service. Finally most developers on SO won't help you make code changes until you show evidence that you've actually tried make the changes yourself. SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: It looks like you're using the older version of the Twilio SDK. I would recommend upgrading to the latest version. There is a guide on how to do that here https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java/migration-guide and full SDK docs and example here https://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/

Comment: thanks for the support.Actually i am not able to import twilio in my netbeans java environment in my device.Actually I need a java program to send message from an array of defined messages. I searched on the internet ,gone through twilio but yet not successfull . Hence it would be a lot a help to me if you teach how to do this?

Comment: Further to Andy's message above, to learn more about sending and messages with Twilio in Java check out the [quickstart guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/sending-via-rest) and the [REST API reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages?code-sample=code-send-a-message-with-an-image-url&code-language=java&code-sdk-version=7.x). If you are having trouble importing Twilio to your environment, that is probably a different question that you should ask and provide more information about.